# exctract code from handler to functions/methods obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to extract code from

```c
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           [self doSomethingWithData:data];
                           outstandingRequests--;
                           if (outstandingRequests == 0) {
                               [self doSomethingElse];
                           }
                       }];
```

to

```c
void AsynchronousRequestCompletionHandler (NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
  ...    
}
```

but I can't:
[image]

in xamarin iOS i did it: instead this

```cs
TextLogin.ShouldChangeCharacters += () => { some code...};
```

made this:

```cs
TextLogin.ShouldChangeCharacters += LoginAndPassValidator;

// ... some code

bool LoginAndPassValidator (UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
{
    BtnLogin.Enabled = (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (TextLogin.Text)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (TextPass.Text));
    if (BtnLogin.Enabled) {
        BtnLogin.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
    } else {
        BtnLogin.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Gray, UIControlState.Normal);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can I make this extraction in obj C?

Comment: Code means what? Response statuscode?

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                       AsynchronousRequestCompletionHandler(response, data, error);
                   }];
```

EDITED:

You can make convenient things with C++:

```
template <class T>
void SendAsyncRequest(NSURLRequest* request, NSOperationQueue* opQueue, T func)
{
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                               queue:opQueue
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                       func(response, data, error);
                   }];
}
```

And then you will be able call this (don't forget rename .m into .mm):

```
SendAyncRequest(request, [NSOperationQueue mainQueue], AsynchronousRequestCompletionHandler);
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: may be exist simply way instead duplicate code?  your code work but dublicate in xamarin ios its simply: TextLogin.ShouldChangeCharacters += LoginAndPassValidator;

Comment: but in xamarin i cam make this: if (LoginAndPassValidator != null) {TextLogin.ShouldChangeCharacters += LoginAndPassValidator; } else { TextLogin.ShouldChangeCharacters += OtherValidator;} and may change this delegates in runtime, its possible in objC?

Answer (score 0):

Note the parameter is a block, not a method. So you can't use a method (or function) instead of it.

```
typedef void (^ResponseCompletionBlock) (NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *);

ResponseCompletionBlock completionHandler = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    [self doSomethingWithData:data];
    outstandingRequests--;

    if (outstandingRequests == 0) {
        [self doSomethingElse];
    }
};

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

If you want to handle it in a method, the simplest solution is

```
ResponseCompletionBlock completionHandler = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     [self asynchronousRequestCompletionHandlerForResponse:response 
                                                   withData:data
                                                   andError:error];
};
```

I don't recommend using plain C functions in this context. Don't use C# language patterns/naming rules in Obj-C.